# Format column in excel to include a phrase based on numerical results in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a datasheet that indicates how much a student has increased or decreased a score on a particular running record.

I would like to insert a column that will include text such as **increase** where the score has increased or **decrease** where the score has decreased, so that I can use the sheet to create a merge document for reports.

So if `Column B` includes a *fall score*, `Column C` includes the *winter score*, and `Column D` includes the *difference*, I would like `Column E` to say **increase** or **decrease** based on `Column D`. How do I get it to do this?

Basically, I need to know how to set rules for a column to include text based on a number in another column. I can figure out the range, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should also [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, for example:

```
     B     C     D

1    5     7     2
2    9     8     -1
3    6     6     0
```

Then cell `E1` should be:

```
=IF(D1>0,"INCREASE",IF(D1<0,"DECREASE", "STABLE"))
```

The formula means that:
If cell D1 is greater than zero then cell E1 will be INCREASE,

and if cell D1 is less than zero then cell E1 will be DECREASE.

In any other case (D1=0) it will be STABLE.